# Prove existence of non-computable double argument function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computability, recursive-algorithms

Recently we've been dealing with computable and non-computable functions, trying to construct different interesting models within the theory. Yesterday, thoughts on one of tasks we've considered during classes lead me to the following question: whether is it possible for non-computable function $F: \mathbb{N}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ to exist, if all this functions projections are computable:

$\forall a \in \mathbb{N}: f(a,x) - \\$ is computable function $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$

**and**

$\forall a \in \mathbb{N}: f(x,a) - \\$ is computable function $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$;

($F$ is not necessary defined for all values from $\mathbb{N}$ - it may be partially defined).

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.  Let the function's range be $\{0,1\}$, such that for each $x\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(x,y)=1$ for exactly one value of $y$; call it $y(x)$, and assume it is strictly increasing with $x$.  (In either words, $f$ is the graph of an increasing function.)
Clearly $f(x,y)$ is computable for each fixed $x$ (it's all zeroes and a single $1$, the location of which can be specified in a finite number of bits), and $f(x,y)$ is also computable for each fixed $y$ (it's either all zeroes or again all zeroes and a single $1$).  But $f(x,y)$ as a function on $\mathbb{N}^2$ is only computable if $y(x)$ is computable.  And certainly we can choose $y(x)$ to be a strictly increasing non-computable function (exercise for the reader).

Comment: Have you, just like I did, neglected the second condition?

Comment: @GyroGearloose: No, I don't think so... each fixed-$x$ or fixed-$y$ projection of this function is computable.  The other answer below works fine as well: just let $f(x,y)$ be zero for $x\neq y$ and let $f(x,x)=g(x)$ be any non-computable function.  Again, each projection is trivially computable (having only a single non-zero value), but the full function is not.

Answer (score 1):

There are already some answers given, so I don't know whether this answer adds anything substantially different. So you are talking about a two argument function $F: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that each "row" and "column" of this function are individually computable, but the function $F$ itself is non-computable?

Can we define $F$ as follows? For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $F(a,b)=BB(n)$ iff one of the two following possibilities is true:

$(1)$ $a=n$ and $b \geq n$

$(2)$ $b=n$ and $a \geq n$.

**Edit:**
On a second thought, why not just have the value of $F$ as $0$ for all non-diagonal entries and $F(n,n)=BB(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. This is probably simpler than above.

Comment: So you are reducing $F(a,b)$ to $F(min(a,b), min(a,b))$?

Comment: @GyroGearloose I don't quite get what you are saying, but yes, I think we will have both as equal in the first example I described (the one before the **Edit:** heading).

Comment: But then $f(y,y)$ is computable by the requirements in the question.

Comment: @GyroGearloose I can't see it written in the requirements of the question. Doesn't the question state that: $(1)$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $x \mapsto F(a,x)$ is computable $(2)$  $\forall a \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $x \mapsto F(x,a)$ is computable? I don't see anything specifically stated for the diagonal.

Comment: Isn't it, that when $F(a,x)$ is computable for any $x$, $F(a,a)$ isn't computable, too?

Comment: @GyroGearloose It doesn't seem to me that there is any necessary implication here. The computability of $x \mapsto F(a,x)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$ doesn't necessarily seem to imply the computability of the diagonal function $x \mapsto F(x,x)$. If we add the stipulation that  we have to have a  total computable function $g$ (single input) such that for each $a \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $g(a)$ returning the index of some program computing $x \mapsto F(a,x)$ , then we are talking about a much different condition.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: 'Computable' applies to a function.  If $a$ is fixed, then $f(a,x)$ must be computable *as a function of $x$*, by the requirements of the problem.  And certainly $f(a,a)$ is computable in some sense, once $a$ is fixed... it's just a single number.  But $f(a,a)$ need not be computable *as a function of $a$*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{ T_n \}$ be an enumeration of all Turing machines. Define $f(x,y)$ to be $1$ if $T_{\min(x,y)}$ halts (on an empty input string), $0$ otherwise.